# Catching a signal for a program

Tags: operating-system, signals

Are there any ways to catch a signal for a program where you don't have access to source code of the program. Is having a signal handler the only way?

Comment: Which operating system? And what action do you want the process to take after catching the signal?

Comment: Linux, I want to print that certain signal has been caught.

Comment: You can run `strace -q -e trace=none yourcommand` and it'll show you when a signal has been delivered. You can use `strace -e trace=none -e signal=int yourcommand` if you just want to trace the SIGINT signal.

Answer (score 3):

trap command traps the signals and other events.

- Format:    trap  command   signal_list
- Example: Clean txt files from /tmp whenever signals(2,15)

```
# vim my_script.sh
    trap "{ /usr/bin/rm -r "/tmp/*.txt" }" SIGINT SIGTERM ERR EXIT
```